# How to get currently logged in user email in side-nav-bar in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I want to get the email of currently logged in user in accountEmail field. But it is  displaying **Instance of 'Future'** in place of email. Below is the function to get the id of currently logged in user:

```
Future <String> getUserId()  async{
  FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  return user.uid;
}
```

And in this way I am getting it:

```
new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: new Text("Admin"),
                accountEmail: new Text(getUserId().toString()),
              ),
```

I am new to flutter and any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `initState`, do the following:

```
FirebaseUser user = null;
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
}
```

Then you can do:

```
new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: new Text("Admin"),
                accountEmail: new Text(user.email.toString()),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using FutureBuilder

```
 UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
      accountName: new Text("Admin"),
      accountEmail: FutureBuilder(
        future: getUserId(),
        builder: (context,snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            snapshot.data;
          }else{
            "-"
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use `user.email.toString()`

Comment: Instance of 'Fututre<String>' is displaying instead of the email of currently logged in user

Comment: Its a type casting issue infact